# How to clean a CSV file using the 'grep' command

Tags: parsing, csv, grep

Assuming that we have the following record `{(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever` What I want is, extract the information, based on the following rule, preferably with 'grep': **if {} contains less or equal to two UNIQUE elements, the ones inside the (), then keep (both) of them, otherwise delete the whole row**. As a further step, I want to extract the values within the (), and finally write the remaining lines in the following form: `XXX1,XXX2,whatever`

**UPDATE:**

For the following input:

```
{(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
{(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
{(XXX1)},whatever,unique=1
{},whatever,unique=0
{(XXX1),(XXX2),(XXX3),(XXX4)},whatever
```

I should get the following output:

```
XXX1,XXX2,whatever,unique=2
XXX1,whatever,unique=1
```

Comment: You cannot (reliably) work on csv data with grep, because cvs entries can span multiple lines. Even if you don't have any of those, grep is probably not up to determining whether some given comma (or whatever your separator is) is inside an entry or separating them.

Comment: Good, thanks! What would you recommend me, then?

Comment: There is http://www.aboutwilson.net/csvgrep/, but I haven't looked into what it can and cannot do. Beyond that, use some proper CSV parser and writer/serializer and implement the logic on top of that. Personally, I'd check for ruby gems, but the choice of language probably depends on what you know.

Comment: what is `whatever` part? can it contain something like `(...),(...)`?

Comment: @kent: No. 'whatever' means the rest of the line and do not require any further transformation. It is just 'pure' CSV data, such as: aaa1,hkah1,kajki7 The only special character it includes is the comma.

Comment: @eualin ok. then see my answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

awk could do it, check this one-liner:

```
awk -F'[}{]' '{split($2,a,",");delete(b);for(x in a)b[a[x]]}length(b)<=2' file
```

let's do a small test:

```
kent$  cat file
ok,{(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
ok,{(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
ok,{(XXX1)},whatever,unique=1
ok,{},whatever,unique=0
nok,{(XXX1),(XXX2),(XXX3),(XXX4)},whatever

kent$  awk -F'[}{]' '{split($2,a,",");delete(b);for(x in a)b[a[x]]}length(b)<=2' file
ok,{(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
ok,{(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
ok,{(XXX1)},whatever,unique=1
ok,{},whatever,unique=0
```

you can see, the `nok` line was removed

**EDIT**

```
 awk -F'[}{]' '{gsub(/[()]/,"");split($2,a,",");delete(b);for(x in a)b[a[x]];l=length(b)}l<=2&&l>0{s="";for(x in b)s=s""x",";sub(/,$/,"",s);y[s]=s $3}END{for(x in y)print y[x]}' file
```

test

```
kent$  cat file
{(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
{(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX1),(XXX2)},whatever,unique=2
{(XXX1)},whatever,unique=1
{},whatever,unique=0
{(XXX1),(XXX2),(XXX3),(XXX4)},whatever

kent$  awk -F'[}{]' '{gsub(/[()]/,"");split($2,a,",");delete(b);for(x in a)b[a[x]];l=length(b)}l<=2&&l>0{s="";for(x in b)s=s""x",";sub(/,$/,"",s);y[s]=s $3}END{for(x in y)print y[x]}' file
XXX1,XXX2,whatever,unique=2
XXX1,whatever,unique=1
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there! Could you please refer to my question? Just post it an update.